# Resizing images using Glade for C

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, glade

I am very new to GTK+ programming and have decided to use Glade for my GUI. I am struggling to find an option on the UI which allows me to resize this massive image that I have, as it blows my entire application out of proportion.

This also applies to my labels - adding in more text doesn't keep them wrapped - the entire UI just expands horizontally. I don't know how to force any of my elements to stick in the same size at all.

[image: Here's what I'm looking at - I don't know the syntax or usage of the styling options and am unsure what to do.]

Are there options in C I should be using? Could someone walk me through styling in Glade? Documentation is really outdated and hard to follow, and I can't find anything useful to help me here.

Comment: What should it look like, other than the label and button text not being cut off? Is that image being cropped unexpectedly, or is the size the only issue?

Comment: The only issue is the size. I just want the image to be smaller, so that the rest of the grid interface resizes appropriately and the text and buttons don't go off the screen. It should be two columns, with one being the image and the second being the same size as the image but filled with labels and a button.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown what your top level container is, but I assume a GtkBox with 2 horizontal items, then your image in the left and another GtkBox (with 4 vertical items) in the right. If this is not correct, then readjust your design. Set the packing scheme for the label to expand ON, and OFF for the buttons.

Your design should look like this:
[image]